# Word 2007 consistently crashes when I use my VPN

Tags: vpn, microsoft-office-2007, crash, network-printer

My Office 2007 consistently crashes when I use it while connected to the VPN.
This happens even with local files.
When I try to paste stuff, it tries to connect to the printer (over VPN) and if I stop the process (which in itself blocks for about a minute), then Word 2007 is bound to crash a few seconds afterwords.
My VPN is Check Point VPN-1 SecureClient

Anyone knows what can be done with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very possibly a problem with the printer driver.

Could you please detail your OS and the OS you VPN to (also 32/64-bits issues), and the printer make, and whether that printer driver is installed locally or not.

Comment: These are hard questions to answer...
* I'm using Win XP (32 bit)
* The print server is Windows 2003 (32 bit)
* The printer is HP LaserJet 4250. Driver is PCL6 from 2007
* Driver is installed locally (I think)

Comment: There is a newer PCL6 driver from 9 May 2008 here - http://tinyurl.com/c4w8f2. On same page, there's an auto-check for printer driver update (requires IE).